# Can't refresh HTML page

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have a problem. I have made a HTML and PHP page with jQuery, jQuery-ui, jQuery mobile, then kineticjs. When switching to another page, do not refresh the whole page. I also tried using `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="URL=aa.php">` but did not work.
In that page I am also using php to get result from that PHP. Here is the code from my php page :

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_POST['address']) && isset($_POST['prefix']) && isset($_POST['levels']) ) {
        require_once 'convert.php';
        $network = new Network($ip, $prefix, $levels);
        print_html($network);
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="URL=aa.php">
        <title>aa</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="js/kinetic-v4.3.2-beta.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h3>aa</h3>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <h3>aa</h3>
                <br />
                <div>
                    <label for="address">Address:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="address">
                    <select id="prefix">
                        <?php for ( $i = 49; $i < 64; $i++ ) : ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>">/<?php echo $i; ?></option>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </select>
                    <label for="subnet">Total Subnets: </label>
                    <input type="text" id="subnets">
                    <button class="btn" id="build"> Build It </button>
                </div>

                <div id="network"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $("#build").click(function(){
                    var subnets = parseInt( $("#subnets").val() );
                    var address = $("#address").val();
                    var prefix = $("#prefix").val();
                    var levels = $("#subnets").val();
                    $.post("aa.php", {address:address, prefix:prefix, levels:levels}, function(response){
                        $("#network").html(response);
                        $("#network > .branch").show();
                        $("#network .open-children").click(function(){
                            $(this).text('-');
                            $(this).parent().children(".branch").toggle();
                            return false;
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

whether the problem comes from too many javascript?

Comment: Looks like you include jQuery twice. Remove the second reference.

Comment: I have erased the jQuery after div..The result is same..not work..

Comment: Instead of inserting the whole source try to reduce the code to the minimum that still produces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Meta refresh should work so:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=aa.php">
```

Comment: but it can't..I don't how why..If I use what you said, after I refresh my page manually it always refresh every second..

Answer (score 0):

You can use it without JS.

```
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='?nojs=1'"></noscript>
```

Check if you have any errors in console and remove them. Also you should detect if you have mobile or PC version of browser and include either jquery-1.9.1.js or jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js

you can also use

window.location

with setInterval or setTimeout it'll do the same. But you can't have any JS errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this javascript code for refresh your page:

```
document.location.reload();
```

or change your location if you want:

```
document.location = "http://google.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=aa.php">
```